# Remove easily duplicate entries in a SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to easily remove duplice entries in this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mups` (
  `idgroupe` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `fan` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Example :

if ive got 3 entries like that

```
  ('36','143')
  ('36','143')
  ('36','143')
```

I just want to keep one row

An idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you consider to be a duplicate record?  Where `idgroupe` is the same, where `fan` is the same, or only where they are both the same?

Comment: if they are both the same in the table

Comment: here you are creating table with columns not entries

Comment: i know its just the structure of my table

Answer (score 2):

If you define a `UNIQUE` index over both columns using the `IGNORE` keyword, MySQL will drop all but a single copy of every record:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mups ADD UNIQUE (idgroupe, fan)
```

Comment: mysql answer me #1062 - Duplicate entry '0-19306' for key 'idgroupe'
ALTER IGNORE TABLE mups ADD UNIQUE (
idgroupe,
fan
)

Comment: But no duplicates where deleted

Comment: @user1965147: You have encountered a [known bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40344); issue `SET SESSION old_alter_table=1` before the above command.

Comment: Still got the same got after SET SESSION old_alter_table=1 before the above command

Comment: server: 5.5.25a-1~dotdeb.1-log

Comment: I still got no solution.. Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**If there are no Foreign Key relationships pointing to this table**, you could use a (temporary) table and copy distinct rows there:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_mups AS 
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM mups ;
```

Then delete everything from `mups`:

```
DELETE 
FROM mups ;
```

Add the `UNIQUE` constraint you want:

```
ALTER TABLE mups
ADD CONSTRAINT mups_UQ
  UNIQUE (idgroupe, fan) ;
```

Get the data back:

```
INSERT INTO mups 
  (idgroupe, fan)
SELECT idgroupe, fan
FROM temp_mups ;
```

And safely drop the temp table:

```
DROP TABLE temp_mups ;
```

Tested in SQL-Fiddle: **[test-1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8aa3/1)**

Comment: After INSERT INTO mups 
  (idgroupe, fan)
SELECT idgroupe, fan
FROM temp_mups ; i got the error  Duplicate entry '8147-6460' for key 'mups_UQ'

Comment: Yes exactly...! 
Server version: 5.5.25a-1~dotdeb.1-log (Debian)

Comment: Can you try `INSERT INTO mups (idgroupe, fan) SELECT DISTINCT idgroupe, fan FROM temp_mups ;`

Comment: then i got `#1062 - Duplicate entry '15989-8916' for key 'mups_UQ'`

Comment: Did you by accident run the `INSERT` twice (the first it succeeded and the 2nd time it shows the error)? What does `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mups;` show? And does `SELECT * FROM mups;` show results?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out what the duplicates are like this:

```
SELECT idgroupe, fan, count(*)
FROM mups
GROUP BY idgroupe, fan
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Cant i delete all the duplicates with only one query ?